# My try catch finds objects that are not displayed anymore, leading my test to fail

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I'm having an odd behavior. When I try catch an object that is not on the android screen anymore, the UiAutomator still finds it and fail my test.

Does any of you have an idea why is it happening and how to fix?

Here is an example of code that fails:

```
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
UiSelector uiSelector = new UiSelector();
UiObject error = null;

try {
    error = uiDevice.findObject(uiSelector.text("Text"))
} catch (UiObjectNotFoundException notFound) {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Success");
}

assertTrue("Something is wrong. Please verify", error == null);
```

Comment: are you sure there is no `"Text"` on the device screen when you are executing this try..catch block? [Guess: some other element might have same text]

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I added a sleep before executing this block while debugging. There is no other element with the same name and still, uiautomator finds it.

Comment: could you just try and print the attributes of the object that you are finding then

Comment: index, 0 / text, Text / resource-id, com.test.test:id/text / package, com.test.test / content-desc, / checkable, false / checked, false / clickable, false / enabled, true / focusable, false / focused, false / scrollable, false / long-clickable, false / password, false / selected, false / bounds, [30,757][316,830]

Comment: `text, Text / resource-id, com.test.test:id/text` means it does exist on your app not just the screen,though the bounds reflect that it might not have been rendered to an appropriate place for you to see it on screen..could you instead wrap[height and width] of your elements in the application code. So that you would be able to see the element on device as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that. This item is part of a list and it is dynamically generated. Think about the youtube videos list, my app works very similarly.   When I perform a specific action, this item goes away of the list, and there is the point where the piece of code above still finds it.